# Can this problem be solved or is there something wrong with it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

By selling $45$ lemons for Rs $40$, a man loses $20\%$. How many should he sell for Rs $24$ to gain $20\%$ on the transaction?

Comment: If he loses money selling lemons at Rs40, he can't possibly make any money by selling any number of lemons at a lower price. It's like that joke about the lemon dealer who says he loses money on every lemon he sells. "But I make it up in volume!" he boasts.

Comment: @MJD I don't see the word "each" there.

Comment: @Mike Good call. That is probably the key to understanding the question.

Comment: Begin with $\text{ Let the price of each lemon be 'x'}$.

Comment: Is that last 20 supposed to be 20%?

Comment: Right. It is 20%. It changed on editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a rather involved problem.  If he lost $20\%$, he made only $80\%$ of what the lemons cost him.  He sold them for $\frac{40}{45}=\frac89$ Rs/lemon.  If $x$ is his cost per lemon, we have

$$\frac89=\frac{80}{100}x$$
$$x=\frac89\times \frac54=\frac{10}{9}\text{Rs/lemon}$$

If he wants to make $20\%$ profit on each lemon he sells, he needs to sell them for $120\%$ of x, or $\frac65\times\frac{10}9=\frac43$ Rs/lemon.  Now let $y$ be the number of lemons he should sell.  He sells y lemons at $\frac43$ Rs/lemon.  If this costs Rs $24$, then

$$\frac{4y}3=24$$
$$y=18$$

Comment: Thanks @Mike.. that's exactly what I was looking for